# Bootloading window7 problem

Tags: dual-boot

Whenever I try to load from Ubuntu 14.04 boot loader to windows 7, I select windows7 but it does not start. please help. thank

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the error message that is shown?

The reasons could be that,

a) you might have formated the drive containing Windows 7 and that is preventing the boot loader form booting into your particular operating system.

b) a fault with the bootloader program

To go into details try installing  Grub Customiser by typing the following commands into the terminal of ubuntu ( usually got by pressing ctrl + alt + Tkey)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

you can see the operating systems installed and make necessary edits.

But community can help you better if you can provide the error shown .

Regards

Comment: No error pops up. I select windows 7 and press enter. my screen adjusts its resolution and... again it takes me back to grub. I will try your way and let you know. Thank you very much for responding

Comment: i entered the codes by no operating system appeared